# NSPasteboard availability after the app exit

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspasteboard

ALL,

Have a following question:

If I allocate NSPasteboard, wrote some data into it, the  quit the application, that data will still be available? I won't need to do anything extra?

Or there should be some kind of API call to retain the data in order to paste it into the other application after I exit mine?

TIA!!!

Comment: The data will still be there if you are using the generalPasteboard.

Comment: @red_menace, which means I don't have to do anything special? Great, thx.

Comment: @red_menace, I upvoted you answer. Thx.

Comment: red_menace Please transform your comment into an answer to make this question and answer more visible.